# Finding generator for $(X, Y-1)\subset\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2−1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm coming back to this problem after leaving it unsolved for a while so my memory on this problem is a bit vague but it goes something like this.
Consider the ring $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2−1)$. Now find a generator for the ideal $(X, Y-1)\subset\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2−1)$. The hint that I got was that $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2−1)\cong\mathbb{C}[U,V]/(UV-1)$ which wasn't hard to prove, but I can't seem to progress any further.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And according to this isomorphism, which ideal in $\Bbb C[U,V]/(UV-1)$ does $(X, Y-1)$ correspond to? Maybe a bit easier: Which elements do $X$ and $Y-1$ correspond to?

Comment: I suppose that $(X,Y-1)$ would correspond to the ideal $(\frac{1}{2}(U+V),\frac{1}{2i}(U-V)-1)$ under the isomorphism, but I don't see how this makes things any easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{i}{\iota}$We have the isomorphism in the hint given by $U = X + \i Y$ and $V = X - \i Y$.
Under this isomorphism, the ideal of interest becomes $(U + V, U - V - 2\i)$. (I have scaled the generators by units.)

Note that this is an ideal in the ring $\Bbb C[U, V]/(UV - 1)$. This means we have the relation $UV \color{red}{=} 1$ in the ring. Using this, note that
\begin{align}
(U + V, U - V - 2\i) &= (U + V, 2U - 2\i) \\
&= (U + V, U - \i) \\
&= (V + \i, U - \i) \\
&\color{red}{=} (V + \i UV, U - \i) \\
&= (V(1 + \i U), U - \i) \\
&= (\i V(-\i + U), U - \i) \\
&= (U - \i).
\end{align}

Thus, in the original ring, this gives us
$$(X, Y - 1) = (X + \i Y - \i).$$